# Customize VerifyEmail url in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, email-verification, laravel-10

I’m trying to customize the url embedded inside the verification email, i want to redirect the user to the frontend domain, not on the api domain.

```php
// …

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    // …

    public function boot():void
    {

        VerifyEmail::createUrlUsing(function (/* Get some cb variables here */) {

        //  Update the url here !
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: are you using the laravel auto-generated auth or a custom auth?

Comment: So you wan to render a view after clicking the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how to change the url based on model. This code added a custom attribute which can be accessed using $request->query('type').

```
public function boot(): void
{
    VerifyEmail::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable) {
        if ($notifiable instanceof \App\Models\User) {
            return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                'verification.verify',
                Carbon::now()->addMinutes(120),
                [
                    'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                    'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
                    'type' => 'type1',
                ]
            );
        } elseif ($notifiable instanceof \App\Models\Frontend\AgentRequests) {
            return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                'verification.verify',
                Carbon::now()->addMinutes(120),
                [
                    'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                    'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
                    'type' => 'type2',
                ]
            );
        }
    });
}
```

You can modify the URL instead of returning the link. You can use **str_replace()** function to strip the domain part.